# create error code table in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, database-update

I am integrating a local payment gateway and the payment gateway is providing 60+ error codes with description.

So I would like to save default error codes in a table and get the description based on the error code received.

My installer script as below,

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$installer->getTable('ucs_i2c_errors')};
CREATE TABLE {$installer->getTable('ucs_i2c_errors')} (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `middleware_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `i2c_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `response_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

And my config.xml as below

```
<global>
    <resources>
        <i2c>
            <setup>
                <module>Ucs_Mtom</module>
                <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </i2c>
    </resources>
    <models>
        <mtom>
            <class>Ucs_Mtom_Model</class>
        </mtom>
    </models>
</global>
```

I have to insert those 60+ data into my table.

How can I add those records in my installer script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use data script in addition to your setup script.

> Magento uses two folders to separate the database installation
>   structure, in the sql folder you will put the table, attributes and
>   column creation/modification, and in the data folder you will insert
>   data to the DB.
>
> They are declared at the same time as setup resources, so you can use
>   them right after you put your setup resource on config.xml, these
>   scripts follow the same naming conventions as sql scripts just adding
>   the word 'data', for example data-install-1.0.php,
>   data-upgrade-1.0.1-1.0.2.php, etc

To do so, you can do the following:

Create the following file in your module folder: `data/<yourmodule_setup>/data-install-<yourmodule_version>.php` (`<yourmodule_setup>` is the same as the folder name you used under your `sql` folder to create your install script)

Then the content could be like this:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$data = array(
    array('middleware_code1','i2c_code1','response_description1'),
    array('middleware_code2','i2c_code2','response_description2')
    ... (and so on for each data you want to insert) ...
);

foreach ($data as $entry)
{
    $errorCode = Mage::getModel('i2c/error');
    $errorCode->setMiddlewareCode($entry[0]);
    $errorCode->setI2cCode($entry[1]);
    $errorCode->setResponseDescription($entry[2]);
    $errorCode->save();
}

$installer->endSetup();
```

NB: I have used `Mage::getModel('i2c/error')` but it depends on how you declared your models.

Your need to have your models and resource models declared in your `config.xml`:

```
<models>
    <mtom>
        <class>Ucs_Mtom_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>mtom_resource</resourceModel>
    </mtom>

     <mtom_resource>
        <class>Ucs_Mtom_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <error>
                <table>ucs_i2c_errors</table>
            </error>
        </entities>
    </mtom_resource>
</models>
```

Then your model should look like this: `Model/Error.php`

```
<?php
class Ucs_Mtom_Model_Error extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('mtom/error');
    }
}
```

Then you need to have your resource model declared: `Model/Resource/Error.php`:

```
<?php

class Ucs_Mtom_Model_Resource_Error extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {   
        $this->_init('mtom/error', 'id');
    }
}
```

Finally declare your collection model: `Model/Resource/Error/Collection.php`:

```
<?php

class Ucs_Mtom_Model_Resource_Error_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('mtom/error');
    }

}
```

Comment: I updated my question with model handler in config.xml, so mine should be `Mage::getModel('mtom/error')` right? So Error.php should be placed inside Model folder right? what should I have in Error.php?

Comment: @invissible see my edited answer.

Comment: Excellent.. +1 its working fantastic